# ASUS M4A785TD: 1 long beep two short beeps

Tags: post

I've been having problems with my home server restarting after a few minutes of being turned on. Here are the major components.

- [ASUS M4A785TD-M EVO](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A785TDM_EVO/)
- AMD Athlon II X2 250
- [HIS Radeon HD 5770](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814161338)

I opened it up and noticed that the heat pipe on the side of the graphics card were really hot, and after further inspection found that the fan for the GPU was so gunked up with dust it wasn't spinning. So I assumed the the GPU was overheating and the cause of the restarting.

So I pulled the GPU out and took off the fan and cleaned it up. I hooked it up to a 12v powersupply to confirm it would run.

Yet after reinstalling the card I could not get anything to show up on the screen and instead I hear 1 long beep followed by 2 short beeps. It then kept. repeating this beep pattern.

Here's what I found on the ASUS website:

```
3. "One long and two short beeps" from speaker

Abnormal detected in Memory, please confirm whether memory is correctly 
installed on motherboard.

Please refer to Motherboard manual for related instruction about memory.

https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1029959/
```

So i tried reseating all 4 ram sticks, but that did not solve the problem.

I then tried clearing the the CMOS with the "Clear RTC" jumper, as well as removing the CMOS battery for 5 min.

At this point I've unplugged everything from the motherboard except the CPU, yet it's still giving me beeps. I've also tried installing each of my 4 RAM sticks individually in slot A1...still beeps.

I'm at a loss. This computer has been running fine for years. Anyone have a suggestion for something else to try?

Comment: Did you test the memory?.....https://www.memtest.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulled out the motherboard and found this on the back ;-(

[image]

I think I must have turned the computer on with one of the DIMMS in backwards, or not seated all the way. Anyway It's an old board so I found a replacement of the same motherboard with a much faster processor then what I had previously on ebay for $60.